# Reassignment of array does not trigger change detection in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Why change detection does not trigger in below case

Persons.address = result.address

I want to assign person.address array to the result.address

Result object is coming from api save result.
So after save completed successfully I want to reassign my array to that result array

View is not updating after this reassignment
It is still showing old data

Comment: at one place, you have written Persons.address (capital P), at at other place, you have written, person.address, which is different. So can you please share a piece of real code? it will be helpful. If everything is fine, then it should work.

Comment: The issue is most likely because you mutated the array elements while the array references stays the same. If you try `Person.address = [...result.address];` it should trigger the change detection, or via `Object.assign`.